# Why is it "argument" instead of "arguement"?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, silent-letters

Why would you replace the <e> in argue before affixing <-ment>?

Comment: It is fairly normal to drop the silent "e" when adding a suffix to such a word (though I can't offhand think of other examples).  As to "Why?" the answer is "Because this is English".

Comment: @HotLicks - what about “amazement” and the silent “e”?

Comment: @user5768790 In that case it would change the sound of that second *a,* since there's a consonant between it and the *e.*

Comment: @user5768790 "Amazement" would create CC run with the /e/ dropped. Argument doesn't.

Comment: What I find more strange is the dropping of the **e** from **dge** when adding -ment, in words like *judgment* or *abridgment.* To me, **dge** sounds like a *j,* but **dg** seems like it should sound the way it's spelled.

Comment: @spoko - Ment - 
Generally attached to stem without changes, except when the stem ends in -dge, where the -e is sometimes dropped, as in abridgment, acknowledgment, judgment, and lodgment, with the forms without -e being preferred in American English. Of these, judgment is the most significant, and usage varies globally. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ment

Comment: @user5768790 Yeah, I know. That's what I'm saying is weird. ??

Comment: I honestly thought it was *judgement*. And I don't get any complaint from my spell-checker for that ...

Comment: You're welcome to spell these *judgement* and *acknowledgement* if you prefer.

Comment: ^Don't make me get argumentative... :)

Comment: @spoko: What I find even more strange is the complete set of rules for English pronunciation. I don't know any other language where the sequence of phonemes for a given word is so different from the sequence of letter than in English. The dutch author Gerard Nolst Trenité wrote a famous poem about this, called "the chaos". You can and listen to it while reading it on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1edPxKqiptw).

Answer (score 12):

It wasn't formed within English at all. According to the OED, this is the etymology of the word:

> French *argument* (13th cent.), < Latin *argūmentum* , < *arguĕre* (or refashioning, after this, of Old French *arguement* , < *arguer* )

I don't know Latin, but I think I found a pattern:

- **indument** (obsolete) from "Latin *indumentum* garment, clothing, < *induĕre*"
- **integument** from "Latin *integumentum* covering, < *integĕre* to cover"
- **involument** (obsolete) from "late Latin *involūmentum* (Vulgate), wrapper, < *involvĕre* to involve"

I think Latin just drops the ending -ere from its verbs when adding -mentum.

Comment: It's a loan word. Wow. Thank you so much for your research!!

Answer (score 8):

As [Laurel’s answer suggests](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/435116/24589), “dropping” the *e* comes from Latin, rather than English.

To give a little Latin background, *arguere* (“to enlighten,” “to plea,” “to make a case”) is the infinitive form of *arguo* (“I [do those things]”). The principle parts of a Latin verb are usually given as

- the 1st-person–present–indicative–active (*arguo*, “I make a case”),
- the infinitive (*arguere*, “to make a case”),
- the 1st-person–perfect–indicative–active (*argui*, “I made a case”), and
- the supine (*argutum*, also “to make a case,” but this time as a noun phrase<sup>1</sup>).

So here you can see that *-ere* is the suffix used to form the infinitive form of the verb, which is perhaps the most “neutral” form it has (not being attached to any particular actor or tense). Notably, the imperative form of the verb takes the infinitive and drops the *-re*, so ordering someone to make a case would literally be *argue* (pronounced differently, though, since the *e* would not be silent and there would be no *y* sound, so closer to *ar-goo-eh* though that makes the *e* sound seem too strong).

Meanwhile, *argumentum* is also a Latin word, formed as *arguo* + *mentum* (“a tool or aid”), in short, a tool or aid for making your case. *Argumentum* doesn’t “drop” an *e*, it simply never had one. It instead drops *o*, as that is the 1st-person–present–indicative–active suffix and not really relevant to the noun that was made from it.

---

1. <sub>For the curious, the difference between the infinitive and supine—which actually do exist in English as concepts, even though they use the same words—is roughly this: “I go to make a case,” is the infinitive, i.e. *Arguere eo.* “To make a case is the best choice,” is the supine, i.e. *Argutum est optio optima.*</sub>

Comment: Good answer. You might be interested in the Latin stack exchange: https://latin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The *e* isn't dropped in "argument", it's *added* in "argue". The root is "argu". The noun "argument" is formed by adding "ment" to the root. The present participle is formed by adding "ing" to the root. The present tense is formed by adding "e" to the root.

Answer (score -1):

In UK the spelling includes the E.
In US it doesn't.
Easy.
Though in Australia, once all spelling words the UK way, now adopting more American spelling in dropping the E in eg:
Arguement -> Argument.
Abridgement -> Abridgment.     Judgement -> Judgment.
Colour -> Color.
All right -> Alright

Just these off top of my head.
But I can't spell WITHOUT the E... just feels wrong LOL

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and read the [FAQ].

Comment: "In UK the spelling includes the E." No, it doesn't usually. The citations in the Oxford English dictionary's entry for the word *argument* show that the spelling with U directly followed by M has been in common use since the word entered English.